# Why is my position:absolute <div> not positioned in relation to its parent?

Tags: css

I understand that if I wrap an outer div with a relative position around a div with an absolute position, then the absolute positioning of the inner div will be relative to the outer div (duh).

However when I do this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .outer {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 700px; }

.inner {
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer; 
bottom: 20px;
left: 5px;}
```

It makes the inner align with the browser window, not the relative div! I'm very stumped on this simple concept, I've been able to do this sort of thing before but I must be doing something wrong.

Here is the complete jsfiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/DDYUK/1/

Comment: "It makes the inner align with the browser window, not the relative div!" - *What* relative `<div>`? `<div class="outer">` doesn't have `position:relative;`.

Comment: One "mnemonic" for me is that "absolute is relative to the nearest relative parent". An element with absolute positioning will position itself in the specified position within the nearest container with "relative" position. Note that this container with relative positioning will keep its natural flow.

Answer (score 4):

`.outer` is never given the CSS property `position:relative`

```
.outer { 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 700px; 
}
```

Comment: ah I thought relative was default! I don't know how I missed that in css class >_> thanks for being kind to the noob, that goes for everyone too!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not apply `position:relative;` to the .outer div, it will default to `position:static`. Absolutely positioned divs will be positioned relative to the closest parent that is positioned relatively. If there is none, it will be positioned relative to the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

update css [here fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/DDYUK/2/)

i update in your jsfiddle

**use relative in outer div**

```
.twitter-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 700px; }

  .twitter-box p {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 69px; }

  .twitter-box img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; }

  .twit {
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer; 
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 5px;}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually point out what the OP's misunderstanding was, and your code seems quite different to the code in the question.

Comment: ah! Yes I see, sorry I hadn't looked at the OP's fiddle.